# Unable to execute a powershell script from c#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I've done the following code to execute a powershell script:

```
public static void LaunchCommand(string command, IList<String> arguments)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Launching powershell command: {command} {String.Join(" ", arguments)}");
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        // specify the script code to run.
        ps.AddScript(command);
        ps.Streams.Debug.DataAdded += OnDebugAdded;
        ps.Streams.Information.DataAdded += OnInfoAdded;
        ps.Streams.Warning.DataAdded += OnWarningAdded;
        ps.Streams.Error.DataAdded += OnErrorAdded;
        //Transformation into a non-generic version
        ArrayList argumentsList = new ArrayList();
        foreach (string argument in arguments)
        {
            argumentsList.Add(argument);
        }

        // specify the parameters to pass into the script.
        ps.AddParameters(argumentsList);

            Collection<PSObject> pipelineObjects = ps.Invoke();

        // print the resulting pipeline objects to the console.
        foreach (var item in pipelineObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.BaseObject.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ps.HadErrors+" -"+ps.HistoryString);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Commaned finished");
}
```

(the .DataAdded just write to console.writeline the new message)

But I hit this:

```
Launching powershell command: F:\Dev\AAA\scripts/start.ps1 F:\Dev\AAA\scenarios/BBB/config.json
System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: File F:\Dev\AAA\scripts\start.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
 ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: File F:\Dev\AAA\scripts\start.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.AuthorizationManager.ShouldRunInternal(CommandInfo commandInfo, CommandOrigin origin, PSHost host)
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.ShouldRun(ExecutionContext context, PSHost host, CommandInfo commandInfo, CommandOrigin commandOrigin)
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandProcessor(CommandInfo commandInfo, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, Nullable`1 useLocalScope, SessionStateInternal sessionState)
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandProcessor(String commandName, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, Nullable`1 useLocalScope)
   at System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext.CreateCommand(String command, Boolean dotSource)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.AddCommand(PipelineProcessor pipe, CommandParameterInternal[] commandElements, CommandBaseAst commandBaseAst, CommandRedirection[] redirections, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

I've searched a lot, I've executed as admin this commands, both in x86 and x64 commands prompt:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

And if I execute this myself(copy paste in the command line) it works, it only fails when launching from visual studio.

Any idea what is going on?

I'm on windows 10 pro(latest updates) + VS2019(latest updates also). The console app that I'm doing is on .Net Core 3.1. I do run VS as my simple-normal user(as will the end program).

Comment: What about sending the command to set the execution policy. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420799/enabling-execution-policy-for-powershell-from-c-sharp#answer-56910697).

Comment: @user1672994 oh? It works! Seems weird security, that an user cannot execute script but can execute the commande to allow it? Anyway, could you add this as answer?

Comment: @JAN - Thanks, Adding as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the execution policy as command in power-shell object.

```
 powershell.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddArgument("Unrestricted")
    .AddParameter("Scope","CurrentUser");
```

Comment: Well, apparently in the other system we have, this isn't enough at least :(